# Error when make a select into sqlite from firefox add-on

Tags: javascript, sqlite, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm using the [sqlite.js](https://github.com/julianceballos/sqlite-jetpack) librarie on a firefox add-on that I'm writing.

I have inserted a lot of data whitout problems, but, when I try to make this very simple select

```
function selecionaUsuarioPorNome (nome, teste){
    sqlite.execute("select * from Usuario;", function(result,status){
        cm.enviaMensagem ("rows = " + result.rows + "\ncols = " + result.cows);
        for(var i=0;i<result.rows;i++){
            for(var j=0;j<result.cols;j++){
                console.log(result.data[i][j]);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I got the follow error:

> [17:08:29,013] [Exception... "'Error: The page is currently hidden and
>   can no longer be used until it is visible again.' when calling method:
>   [mozIStorageStatementCallback::handleCompletion]"  nsresult:
>   "0x8057001c (NS_ERROR_XPC_JS_THREW_JS_OBJECT)"  location: "native
>   frame ::  ::  :: line 0"  data: no]

The structure of my projet is:

```
/
|
|___Lib
. . |
. . |____ main.js
. . |____ bd_manager.js
. . |____ sqlite.js
```

And in the main.js I put the main function:

```
exports.main = function (options, callbacks) {
    // quando o add-on é instalado
    if (options.loadReason == "install"){
        // call to test if I can get the user from the database.sqlite
        bd.selecionaUsuarioPorNome ("vitor", function (){});
    }
}
```

Someone knows this error?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You automatically mark this question as solved by accepting an answer (which you already did).

Comment: "Living and learning". Thank you, @ComFreek.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seem to have anything to do with SQLite. The error is generated when you try to send a message to a content script (worker) that is attached to a page which isn't loaded anymore, but still in the back-forward cache (bfcache). So the worker you try to send a message to is attached to a page the user or your add-on navigated away from already.

Your callback, which is executed from the `handleCompletion` wrapper in `sqlite.js`, triggers this error. Likely the following line, as the other lines seem OK and this one is the only one without source code for it.

```
cm.enviaMensagem ("rows = " + result.rows + "\ncols = " + result.cows);`
```

Without knowing more of your code (a full, reproducible example), I cannot tell you more than this.

Comment: Oh, it was really that. This "cm" is a module that I had make to communicate with the content script. And this function "cm.enviaMensagem" sends a message to the content script, then, the content script shows this message on a alert (just another way to debug the add-on).

Comment: I think that I understood. This function is called when the add-on _install_, so, the content script is not yet attached to any page and the worker fails to send the message _"rows = " + result.rows + "\ncols = " + result.cows_.
Thank you very much!